# Viewport height / width returning decimal value?

Tags: css, viewport-units

Viewport height usually returns an integer value; however I am now noticing it returning a value with 2 decimal points.

Why / how do viewport units get rounded?

(Additionally, I am not resizing my browser window -- yet 100vh returns 616px sometimes, other times 616.36px)

Comment: I believe that this is browser dependent, you could probably google this.

Comment: What browser / device and how do you get the viewport size? :)

Comment: Chrome, MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 3):

The specification merely prescribes that 1 unit of `vw` is:

> 1% of viewport’s width

This *ought* to be reasonably precise, as 100 of these units should fill the entire width, so rounding will cause problems here.

The CSS definition of number includes integers and decimals see [v2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#numbers) or [v3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#numbers).

In the cases of the browsers that return an integer, if the view port is not coincidentally exactly divisible by 100, and if the result of 1vw * 100 is significantly off - it is worth raising a bug with the browser vendor.

Result of browser test... note that size difference is down to browser chuff and tool size.

Firefox seems to reliably calculate to 4dp:

```
height: 3.06667px;
width: 6.76667px;
```

An old version of IE I have lying around similarly reliable, but to 2dp:

```
height: 3.78px;
width: 6.76px
```

How are you obtaining your numbers?

Comment: Thanks for this background information -- the specific oddness of this issue for me is that my browser window is the exact same size (no resize, no change), but 100vh sometimes returns a different value (616px vs. 616.36px). Any ideas why? Thanks again.

Comment: At 100vh that is quite a small difference (0.00 per unit rounded to 2dp)... although it is strange. I have added some results from browser tests I have just run. Ultimately, we probably need to know the browser and your method of obtaining numbers.

Comment: I'm running Chrome 46 on a MacBook Pro, OS X Yosemite. 100vh is simply applied in the CSS. True a very small difference, but the inconsistency can affect other logic on the page (although I have a fix for this); it's more for my own knowledge I'd like to understand why this happens. Thank you again!

Comment: Are you actually seeing a less-than-full-height result? I am guessing that although you are seeing the slight difference reported, there is never a visible difference - so it is just a sub-pixel oddity.